# fetch rails json data from heroku with ajax to static website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json, heroku

I have a problem getting json data to display in a static website. the data comes from a simple ruby on rails REST service - which is located on heroku. in this example I am just using it from localhost. Right it says that my data is undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({  
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/projects.json", 
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      success: function(data) { 
        alert(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, value) { 
          var v = JSON.parse(value);
          $("<ul><li>" + v.name + "</li><li>" + v.description + "</li><li>" +v.tech + "</li></ul>")
            .appendTo($("#tech"));
        });
      }
    }
  });

});
```

my other question is how do I append it to the attributes name, description, tech - this in html:

```
<section id="projects">
        <h2>
            Projects
        </h2>
         <article id="project">
             <img id="project-image" src="" alt=""/>
            <label id="name">

             </label>
             <ul id="tech">
                <li>

                 </li>
                 <li>

                 </li>
             </ul>
             <p id="description">

             </p>
         </article>
```

Comment: What happens when you visit http://localhost:3000/projects.json in your browser?  Does this display the JSON you intended?

Comment: it gives me json back from all my projects

Comment: Why is your success function inside data element?

Comment: if success, it should take the data, go through element and append to html elements. but I am not sure if there is a standard way of doing this...

Comment: @PerJohannessen - all the callbacks should be first-level elements of the object passed to `$ajax`. I've noticed that passing it to `data` element still makes it to be called (not sure why), however it doesn't behave as it should then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added this in my projects_controller:

```
 def index
  @projects = Project.all
  projects = @projects.to_json
  respond_to do |format|
  format.json {render :json => projects, :callback => params[:callback]}
 end
end
```

and on the client/ajax side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({  
    type: "GET",
    url: "heroku_url/projects.json", 
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { 
    alert(data);

    $.each(data, function(index, value) { 

    $("<article id='project'><label id='name'>"+data[index].name+"</label>
    <pid='tech'>"+data[index].tech+"</p><p id='description'>"+data[index].description+"
    </p></article><br />").appendTo($("#projects"));

     });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@BroiSatse is right - success should not be inside data. Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({  
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://localhost:3000/projects.json", 
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) { 
        alert(data);

        $.each(data, function(index, value) { 
          var v = JSON.parse(value);

          $("<ul><li>" + v.name + "</li><li>" + v.description + "</li><li>" +v.tech + "</li></ul>")
                                    .appendTo($("#tech"));
        });
      }
    });
 });
```

Comment: okay, now I am getting this: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/projects.json?_=1399384895492. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @PerJohannessen - Try changing `dataType` to `jsonp`

Comment: it removed error message and I can see it's trying to fetch from the server. but it's not appending to any element...

Comment: seems like I don't have anything in data